# When using CheckBoxFor in MVC3, how can I use JQuery to only select the CheckBox INPUT?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

CheckBoxFor renders a hidden field with the same name ([and for good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860940/asp-net-mvcwhy-does-the-checkboxfor-render-an-additional-input-tag-and-how-can))

I need to enable/disable some other INPUT fields based on the value of the CheckBox when the page loads. However, I can't get the JQuery selector right. My function ends up firing twice because the selector is getting both the CheckBox and the Hidden input fields.

This is what I have tried and neither work:

```
$('input[name$="Selected",type=checkbox]').each(function (){
   alert('here ' + this.name);
   EnableOrderItemDropDowns(this);
});

$('input[name$="Selected"],:checkbox').each(function (){
   alert('here ' + this.name);
   EnableOrderItemDropDowns(this);
});
```

Neither of these approaches work. The latter approach still doesn't filter to just the CheckBox inputs, so the call to EnableOrderItemDropDowns still fires twice.

Comment: Once again, the solution presents itself to me right after I post to StackOverflow.. Oh well. ($('input[name$="Selected"]:not(:hidden)'))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[name$="Selected"][type="checkbox"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

The hidden field that is generated does not contain an ID

So you can do:

```
$("#Selected")
```

The only element you will have is the checkbox