# Correct way of knowing if a checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, checked

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

I am a little bit confused about how the input of type checkbox works.

If I set a value, say 1, on a checkbox, I see that regardless of the checkbox is checked or not, the value that I get when the form is submitted is 1.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
```

So, the correct way to see if a checkbox is checked is to use the `checked` from jQuery? Or how it can be done correctly?

Comment: No, I just want to know if I have to do it with jQuery, or if I can use the value to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkbox values should not get submitted if they are not checked.

If you want to check with jQuery, I would always use:

```
var isChecked = $('#checkbox').prop('checked');
```

Or

```
var isChecked = $('#checkbox').is(':checked');
```

With JavaScript, you have to understand the difference between *attributes* and *properties*. `checked` is both a property and an attribute. However, the *attribute* checked isn't always updated when the `checked` *property* of a checkbox changes (in some browsers it is). Think of the attribute as the value in the HTML markup parsed by the DOM. The `checked` *property* is an actual member of the checkbox **element** in the DOM, which always changes based on whether the box is checked or unchecked in the UI.

If you want to try a foolproof method without needed JavaScript, you can try it the "MVC" way, by rendering a hidden input and a checkbox with the same name, each with appropriate "checked"-state values:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mybox" value="false" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mybox" value="true" />
```

When you submit the form, if you can't find a `mybox` value in the request with a value of "true" then the checkbox was not checked. More about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860940/asp-net-mvcwhy-does-the-checkboxfor-render-an-additional-input-tag-and-how-can).

Comment: So, you can't use the value attribute to decide. It's value is the same whether is checked or not. You always have to check if is checked or not. Right?

Comment: @HommerSmith: Unfortunately the `value` attribute behaves differently in various browsers as to whether form submitting includes the value whether it is checked or not. I made an edit that shows the "MVC" way -- a sort of fool-proof method to know whether a checkbox was really checked.

Answer (score 1):

in order to check if the checkbox is actually checked you must use

```
'boxname.checked==""
```

as the value will always be there even if the box is **not checked**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')
```

This returns `true` if checked, and `false` if not.

In answer to your comment on the question, there is not much to be gained by the value when you need the checked state.

Answer (score 0):

`check` is the property of `checkbox` tag, so u have to check if it is set, no other value.