# Why does query string parameter get included twice - asp.net boolean

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, strongly-typed-view

I've got my Index page with the following code:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IncludeArchive)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IncludeArchive)
    </div>
```

my model is:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string TestNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeArchive { get; set; } 
}

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(SearchModel search)
    {
        var test= db.Test.AsQueryable();

        if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0) {
            if (!search.IncludeArchive) test = test.Where(x => x.Status == "Active");
        } else {
            test= test.Where(x => x.Status == "Active");
        }

        ViewBag.testList = test.ToList();
```

When browsing to the page then choosing the IncludeArchive checkbox to enable it to true, the query string turns to

```
http://localhost:64005/test/?FirstName=&LastName=&TestNumber=&IncludeArchive=true&IncludeArchive=false
```

Why does it include the variable IncludeArchive in the query string twice?

Thanks

Comment: More codes required to understand what causes this.

Comment: can you put balance code for the "Index" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way MVC works with checkboxes. If you browse the HTML of your page you will notice that for each checkbox rendered with an HTML helper you have a hidden field with false value. This makes sure that false value is sent in case a user doesn't select your checkbox. That is actually why you  have two values if you select a checkbox and only one value if you don't select it. For more details you can check this posts also:
[asp.net mvc: why is Html.CheckBox generating an additional hidden input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697299/asp-net-mvc-why-is-html-checkbox-generating-an-additional-hidden-input)
[Why does the CheckBoxFor render an additional input tag, and how can I get the value using the FormCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860940/asp-net-mvcwhy-does-the-checkboxfor-render-an-additional-input-tag-and-how-can)

Hope it helps.