# Get and set selected dropdown value for bool property in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a `dropdown` in which i was able to get/set the selected value when the property is `string`, but when it is `bool` i couldn't able to get/set the value.

//Code:

```
 <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedStatus, Model.SelectedStatusList(), "--Select--")
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedStatus, "Field is required")
        </div>
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to set the value as 0 and 1 instead true and false? that might be the reason its not being parsed properly

Comment: Good idea. But i need to know is there any solution for the above query.

Comment: well, if you look at this way then you need do some javascript code to convert true to 1 or false to 0 prior form submission. I prefer to do it with direc 0 and 1

Answer (score 1):

Dropdowns are used when the domain of the property accept multiple answers, like, what's the color of John's hair? It might be blue, it might be black, white, yellow, etc.

When the property accepts only true or false it's better to use a checkbox.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730746/getting-checkbox-value-in-asp-net-mvc-4) to learn on how to deal with checkboxes and auto-bindings.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730746/getting-checkbox-value-in-asp-net-mvc-4 for an answer.