# mvc 4 asp.net c# passing boolean value from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How can i get Boolean value or the true or false from controller to a Checkbox in View using this:

```
@Html.CheckBox("condition", @ViewData["Condition"])
```

or

```
<input type = "checkbox" checked = "**true or false?**">
```

I have this in my Controller..

```
public ActionResult Member(string sortOrder, string filter, string searchString, int? page, **bool? condition = false**)
```

and in my view is like this

please help me for this...

Comment: It just needs to be `@Html.CheckBox("condition")` And the parameter needs to be `bool condition` (not `nullable`). If the value of `condition` is true, the checkbox will display as checked, otherwise it will be unchecked. But I recommend you use a view model and pass it to the view so you can use the strongly typed HtmlHelper - `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Condition)`

Comment: `checked` is bool attribute. It's mere existence ensures the input is checked. So you don't want to `checked=anything` if false because it shouldn't be there i.e. a non checked checkbox would be `<input type="checkbox" />`  whereas  `<input type="checkbox" checked="false"/>` will tick the box as will `<input type="checkbox" checked="anything-you-like"/>` If the `checked` attribute exists, it will be checked regardless of the value.

Answer (score 2):

update your controller

```
public ActionResult Member(string sortOrder, string filter, string searchString, int? page,bool condition)
{
    ViewData["Condition"] = condition;
    // code line 1
    // code line 2
       ... 
}
```

If you are looking for checkbox check/uncheck code for Razor view

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.condition)
```

Will generate:

```
<input id="condition" type="checkbox" value="true" name="condition" />
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="condition" />
```

How does it work:

If checkbox not checked, form submit only hidden (false)
If checked, then form submit two fields (false and true) and MVC set true for bool property

```
<input id="condition" name="condition" type="checkbox" value="@ViewData["Condition"]" />
```

This will always send default value, if checked

reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731571/2318852

Comment: it's possible that <input type = "checkbox" checked = "true or false?" pass the checked value to a controller?

Comment: Thank you so much @BhavikPatel for this well detailed answer! Helped me out!