# Issue with getting values from DB for checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on an MVC application and save some information into a database. From this information I save some checkbox values which is saved in its own column as

```
string 1, string 2, string 3
```

Now I'm trying to retrieve these values and make the checkbox checked in a different page. However where I should be getting two checkboxes I only get one. The returned values are correct but for some strange reason only one checkbox is displayed in the view

In my controller I have the following code

```
IEnumerable<MyEntity> myEntity = entityRepo.GetAll().Where(a => a.UserId == id);
List<CheckBox> checkBoxList = new List<CheckBox>();
foreach (var items in myEntity)
{
     checkBoxList.Add(
     new CheckBox
     {
         Text = items.EightWaste,
         Checked = true,
         Value = items.EightWaste,
     });
 }
```

Then in the view I've got

```
@foreach(var items in Model.EightWatseChkBox)
{
   @Html.DisplayFor(model => items.Text)
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => items.Checked)
}
```

And my UI output looks like

[image: Output]

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please.

Comment: What is the value of `myEntity.Count();`? - it look like you only have one item and its `EightWaste` value is `"Defects, Transportation"`

Comment: And as a side note, you `foreach` loop will not bind to you model. You need to use a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` for typeof `CheckBox`

Comment: Have you checked this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730746/getting-checkbox-value-in-asp-net-mvc-4 ?

Comment: All checkboxes in the list saved to one field in the table?
So you only get one record in myEntity.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The count is 1

Comment: @TerryDelahunt Yes I have only one record in myEntity

Comment: @Code, Then I assume you want to create an array using `String.Split()` (and then `String.Join()` to join the selected items back into a single string in the POST method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you provide an example please

Comment: Sure, give me 20 min.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is how I currently save them into the database `string.Join(",", Request.Form["eigthwaste"].Split(',').Where(a => !a.Contains("false")));`

Comment: as Stephen stated, you need separate the string returned from the db into an array or some form of list and iterate thru that to add each individual checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values are stored in on field as a comma separated string, so to generate a checkbox for each 'word', you need to split the string to an array.

```
MyEntity data = entityRepo.GetAll().Where(a => a.UserId == id).FirstOrDefault();

Model.EightWatseChkBox = data.EightWaste.Split(new char[]{ ',' }).Select(x => new CheckBox()
{
    Text = x,
    Checked = true
}).ToList();
```

Note that property `EightWatseChkBox` in your model needs to be `IList<CheckBox>` not `IEnumerable<CheckBox>` so that you can use a `for` loop in the view

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.EightWatseChkBox.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EightWatseChkBox[i].Text)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.EightWatseChkBox[i].Checked)
}
```

and in the POST method, you can join the selected values back again

```
string[] selected = model.EightWatseChkBox.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x => x.Text);
string combined = String.Join(",", selected);
```

For more information on why you cannot use a `foreach` loop to bind to a collection, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) (note if you cannot change the model property to `IList<CheckBox>`, then you can use the `EditorTemplate` option)

Comment: The property in my model is of `List<T>`. Thanks for this, I'll have a go with this and let you know how I get on

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

In your Controller write like below;

```
IEnumerable<MyEntity> myEntity = entityRepo.GetAll().Where(a => a.UserId == id);

ViewBag.Chekboxlist = myEntity;
```

And then your view will be

```
@foreach(var items in Model.EightWatseChkBox)
{
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => items.Text)
       if(ViewBag.Chekboxlist != null)
       {
           IEnumerable<MyEntity> myEntity = (IEnumerable<MyEntity>)ViewBag.Chekboxlist;
           foreach(var item in myEntity )
           {
               @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.Checked)
           }
      }   
}
```