# Handling checkbox in Many-to-Many Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm using MVC 5, EntityFramwork 6, Code first approach

I see a lot of example in using checkbox in entity framework, but I didn't see any case like what I need.

I will use this simple case:

I have two simple `Course` and `Student`, Every Course has many Students. Every Student has many Courses.

In EF models:

Course class is

```
public class Course
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

and Student class is

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

This generates a table in database called `CourseStudents` table which contains 1 composite Primary key and 2 foreign Keys as expected.

THE QUESTION IS:

I want to create a simple `Create` view contains Student name and list of Courses (displayed as checkboxes), the selected checkboxes is stored in `CourseStudents` table

How to do that?

Comment: You need to create view models to represent what you want to display/edit (and your `CourseVM` will contain a property `bool IsSelected` for binding to the checkbox). Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) for an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on submit
1. Create new student object. 
2. add selected courses to student object couse list

```
myStudent.Courses.add(selectedCourse);
```

3. after adding all courses add student to dbContext and  save changes to dbContext

   context.students.add(myStudent)
   context.SaveChanges();

if the student already exist just select it and add courses to selected student list and save changes to dbContext

Comment: How you could use check box, this line of code is not valid `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Courses, new { value=course.ID })@course.Title`

Comment: `foreach(var courseVm in model.Coures){
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk@course.Id" value="@course.Title" checked="@courseVm.isSelected" /> </li>`

Comment: you cant add a check box for a list.

Comment: if you want to do that you need to create a viewModel for your HTML view. in view model you can represent the list of courses as list of Booleans 

and you need to use a for loop
`foreach(var courseVm in model.Coures){
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk@course.Id" value="@course.Title"  /> </li>`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730746/getting-checkbox-value-in-asp-net-mvc-4