# How to change a hidden field value for a checkbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using Razor in my mvc web app.

I have this:

```
@Html.CheckBox(Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name,Boolean.Parse( Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Value ))
```

so, for me here the initial value of this checkbox is TRUE.

Now, if my User sets it to false I wish to change/create a hidden field to show this value is FALSE for use in my postback.

I cannot use @HTML.CheckBoxFor because the value is coming from a XML file and this value could be for a different control that is not a boolean value.

Following the suggested answer route i put in this:

```
@Html.EditorFor( x => x.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Value, Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name)
```

but the value as the value i string a textbox is rendered and not a checkbox.  which is the opoosite to my problem

is null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Checkbox Value in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730746/getting-checkbox-value-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: @demo will look and check that. thanks

Comment: Accepted answer seems what You need

Comment: @demo Hi, this is the opposite scenario to what I want. I have edited my question to explain. Thanks for  the offering though.. :)

Comment: why don't you try binding a click event in jQuery, and then handle it from script ?

Comment: @Shanid Would you like to post an answer please?

Comment: A `CheckBox()` (and `CheckBoxFor()`) is for binding to a bool, not a `string`. Use a view model with properties `string Value` and `bool IsSelected` and use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name)` and `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].IsSelected)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke hi, yes I did it this way on the end. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#chkType").change(function (s, e) {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) $("#hiddenField1").val('1');
            else $("#hiddenField1").val('0');
        });
```

This ought to work, I just copied it from one of my projects. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks will try in a minute.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. A `CheckBox()` and `CheckBoxFor()` method is for binding to a bool, not an `int` or `string` and it will completely screw up model binding if you need to return the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes I agree. Your suggestion above was the way I did it in the end. I forgot to update this question as busy at work :)

Comment: Sorry had to in tick this answer as the convertor on the model was a better approach for me