# MVC @Html.CheckboxFor submits true,false on form submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 5 with EF Code First and have a View model that contains a bool:

```
public bool MyCheckbox { get; set; }
```

I initialize this in my View's get:

```
model.MyCheckbox = true;
```

In the View:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MyCheckbox)
```

Which get rendered as:

```
<input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The field is required." id="MyCheckbox" name="MyCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="MyCheckbox" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

One of my Buttons on the View triggers an Ajax POST to the Controller where I want to look at the checkbox value:

```
bool bValue = Request["MyCheckbox"] == "true";
```

But the value of `Request["MyCheckbox"]` is "true,false" due to the extra hidden field with `name="MyCheckbox"`.

How do I view the value of this checkbox in the controller with Request["..."] and make sense of it (either true or false)?

I also have another bool member in the View model and I use it in a hidden field intentionally. In the model:

```
bool MyHiddenBool { get; set; }
```

In the Controller Get:

```
model.MyHiddenBool = true;
```

In the View:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyHiddenBool)
```

In the Controller (via Ajax POST):

```
bool AnotherBool = Request["MyHiddenBool"] == "true";
```

But the value of `Request["MyHiddenBool"]` is either "True" or "False" instead of "true" and "false".

What gives with this inconsistency and how can I reliably see the values of these two methods of bools in my Views?

Comment: You posted such a good question, Actually I am also stuck with same kind of problem where I want to save the status as true/false in database. I googled almost everything but nothing is much relevant to me. Can you please provide details description about the ViewModel concept which you used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is how you are consuming the form request variable.

In ASP.NET MVC there's probably never a good reason to use Request.Form or it's variants to consume your request data. You need to make a model or put in an argument for the action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostedForm(bool myHiddenBool)
{
  //Frameworks model binder will extract the form field into your variable based on the name
}
```

The following copied from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860940/asp-net-mvcwhy-does-the-checkboxfor-render-an-additional-input-tag-and-how-can)

> This isn't a bug, and is in fact the same approach that both Ruby on
>   Rails and MonoRail use.
>
> When you submit a form with a checkbox, the value is only posted if
>   the checkbox is checked. So, if you leave the checkbox unchecked then
>   nothing will be sent to the server when in many situations you would
>   want false to be sent instead. As the hidden input has the same name
>   as the checkbox, then if the checkbox is unchecked you'll still get a
>   'false' sent to the server.
>
> **When the checkbox is checked, the ModelBinder will automatically take**
>   **care of extracting the 'true' from the 'true,false'**

Comment: Thank you. I changed my Controller to use the View model, even though I only needed a few parms from the post. It still doesn't make sense why MVC returns "True" from a HiddenFor bool value, and "true" from a CheckboxFor. Thank you for the answer. The link was helpful.

Comment: @rwkiii, because `HiddenFor()` uses `,ToString()` to generate the value of the input and `.ToString()` for a boolean returns "True" or "False".