# Html.CheckBoxFor renders two inputs Which becomes an issue In Form Post

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My code is like this

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 30px;">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsVatPaidByInsurer)
</div>
```

Inside Model Class

```
   public bool IsVatPaidByInsurer { get; set; }
```

Inside Controller

```
  public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PayerID,Name,CreatedDate,PayerTypeSelected,ReferingInstitute,ApplicationUserId" +
                                               "IsVatPaidByInsurer,PatientContribution")] Payer payer)
```

I expect this line of code to generate a checkbox on front end, But how it renders is like this (value not true, it's I just checked the checkbox)

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 30px;">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsVatPaidByInsurer field is required." id="IsVatPaidByInsurer" name="IsVatPaidByInsurer" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="IsVatPaidByInsurer" type="hidden" value="false">
</div>
```

As you can see there is two inputs with same name generated (IsVatPaidByInsurer).
And second one's value always false. So when I make my form post I can't get the real value of checkbox.It will interpret always as false there. Can anyone Tel me what This is whole about? and a way to overcome this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC:Why does the CheckBoxFor render an additional input tag and how can I get the value using the FormCollection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860940/asp-net-mvcwhy-does-the-checkboxfor-render-an-additional-input-tag-and-how-can)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 inputs are correct (and without the hidden input you could get incorrect values). If the checkbox is checked, `true, false` is posted back and the `DefaultModelBinder` sets the model value to `true` (the second value is ignored).  If the checkbox is unchecked `false` is posted back (unchecked checkboxes do not post back) so the model property is set to `false`

Comment: But in my case, even though the checkbox is checked I am getting false in controller??

Comment: Show you controller method and the relevant property in the model.

Comment: Looks OK (but why the `[Bind(Include="....")]`?). Do you have any javascript (perhaps disabling the checkbox which means it wont post back)?

Comment: I have made a check on Chrome network tab. Data post back is correct Frist true then false both are sent back to server. But when I take  payer.IsVatPaidByInsurer  inside controller it is always false

Comment: I have found the solution. when I removed Bind[] . it started working correct. But still I don't know what went wrong :)

Comment: Sure you didn't spell it wrong? In any case, any time you find yourself using `[Bind(Include..)]` or `[Bind(Exclude..)]` **stop**  and use a view model instead.