# Html.CheckBoxFor TypeConversition Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have a view model:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
   ...
   public bool Confirmation{ get; set; }
}
```

I use checkbox helper on my view:

```
@model RegisterModel

......
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Confirmation)
```

This checkbox html helper creates:

```
<input id="Confirmation" name="Confirmation" value="true" type="checkbox">
<input name="Confirmation" value="false" type="hidden">
```

On Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(model);
.....
}
```

Let's say some user changes values of inputs to 'xxx' and posts it. Therefore, Model is not valid and we return view. After that, `Html.CheckBoxFor` gives this error:

> The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type
>   'System.Boolean' failed.

Inner Exception:

> System.FormatException: xxx  is not a valid value for Boolean

When we return view: `Model.Confirmation` value is **false** but `Request["Confirmation"]` value is **'xxx'**.

This error comes from `ValueProviderResult` class on `ConvertSimpleType` method. I think, it tries to convert `Request["Confirmation"]` value to boolean and it gives error.

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1031:DoNotCatchGeneralExceptionTypes", Justification = "Conversion failure is not fatal")]
private static object ConvertSimpleType(CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
{

.....
    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(destinationType);
    bool canConvertFrom = converter.CanConvertFrom(value.GetType());
    if (!canConvertFrom)
    {
        converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(value.GetType());
    }
    if (!(canConvertFrom || converter.CanConvertTo(destinationType)))
    {
        // EnumConverter cannot convert integer, so we verify manually
        if (destinationType.IsEnum && value is int)
        {
            return Enum.ToObject(destinationType, (int)value);
        }
             string message = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, MvcResources.ValueProviderResult_NoConverterExists,
                                           value.GetType().FullName, destinationType.FullName);
        throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
    }

.....
}
```

How can I fix or avoid this error?

Comment: This is weird. Why does `CheckBoxFor` create two inputs with exactly same name?

Comment: "Let's say some user changes values of inputs to 'xxx' and posts it." What do you mean by this? You mean the user changes the html source?

Comment: Yes @ataravati user changes html sources and posts.

Comment: @SantiagoHernández - two inputs get created.  If the checkbox is not checked, it doesn't get posted.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860940/why-does-the-checkboxfor-render-an-additional-input-tag-and-how-can-i-get-the-v

Comment: Well, can't you change the value to false in case of `ModelState.IsValue == false`?

Comment: @Joe oh, wow. I didn't know that, thanks :)

Comment: Are you using ajax? or manipulating posted data?

Comment: Thanks @ataravati I changed my model.isvalid code to        `if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                bool confirmation = bool.TryParse(Request["Confirmation"],out confirmation);
                ModelState.Remove("Confirmation");
                request.Confirmation = confirmation;
                return View(request);
            }` But I dunno why helper tries to get value from request beside of model.

Comment: @MaDeRkAn, That is the default behavior (to use the values from `ModelState` in preference to model values). Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111) for an explanation. But since this could only happen as a result of a malicious user, why not just let the exception be thrown?

Comment: Don't change the value of the check box, or don't use the `CheckBox` helper.

Comment: Thanks for information @StephenMuecke .But I didn't understand: why will l let the malicious users to use our exception handling resources for a public form ?

Comment: I'm saying that in order for a value other that `False` to be posted, a malicious user must be manipulating the value of the hidden input (e.g. posting a value using fiddler in order to try and cause you app to fail). So why not just redirect them to an error page telling them to ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to @StephenMuecke this is default behavior. You can check detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26664111/3432471)

According to @ataravati we should handle this on `model.IsValid==false`. If model is not valid, We remove the value of checkbox and assign new one. Therefore We don't get any error when we return view.

```
 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                bool confirmation;

                bool.TryParse(Request["Confirmation"],out confirmation);
                ModelState.Remove("Confirmation");
                request.Confirmation = confirmation;
                return View(request);
            }
```

According to @StephenMuecke if checkbox input value is not boolean, the user is malicious for sure. Therefore we redirect user to another action which has tracking/blocking ip algorithm and returns 404 as a view.

```
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                bool confirmation;
                if (bool.TryParse(Request["Confirmation"], out confirmation))
                    return View(request);
                return RedirectToAction("Http404", "Errors"); //This not just redirecting 404, it has also tracking/blocking ip algorithm.
            }
```