# Adding a Class to a Table Row Disables Editing TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a table containing several columns one of which is a `checkbox` which indicates the vote is invalid.  When the user selects this `checkbox` I add a "vote-invalid" class to the row at which point a textarea in the adjoining column can no longer be selected for input.

The HTML for the row is;

```
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox"
              id="Lots_0__Invalid" 
              name="Lots[0].Invalid"
              value="true"
              data-val="true" 
              data-val-required="The Invalid field is required.">

       <input name="Lots[0].Invalid" type="hidden" value="false">
    </td>
    <td>
       <textarea id="Lots_0__Note" 
                 name="Lots[0].Note"
                 class="text-box multi-line" 
                 data-val="true" 
                 data-val-length="The note/comment cannot be longer than 500 characters" 
                 data-val-length-max="500"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and the script to add/remove the class is;

```
$("[id$='_Invalid']").click(function (evt) {
    var me = this;
    $tr = $(this).closest("tr");

    if (me.checked) {
        $tr.addClass("vote-invalid");
        $tr.find("textarea").prop("contentEditable", true);
    }
    else {
        $tr.removeClass("vote-invalid");
    }
});
```

Before the Invalid `checkbox` is selected the `textarea` is editable. When "Invalid" is checked the class is added to the row but I can no longer edit the `textarea`; I cannot get the `textarea` to accept focus by clicking in it or tabbing. When "Invalid" is unchecked I can edit the `textarea` again.

As the code above shows I have tried setting the "`contentEditable`" attribute to true with no success.

When the page is first loaded the textarea has the following properties;

```
disabled: false
contentEditable: inherited
readOnly: false
```

After checking "Invalid" the properties are;

```
disabled: false
contentEditable: true
readOnly: false
```

The classes used are;

```
.vote-invalid{
        background-color: orange !important;
        color: white;
    }

    .vote-invalid:hover{
        background-color: darkorange !important;
    }
```

Comment: In your piece of code the textarea dont get disabled plus the classes arent avaible for test... hard to help this way;

Comment: This is exactly my point.  I am not disabling the textarea but after adding the class to the row I can't edit the textarea control.  I have added the classes if this is any help.

Comment: both of your inputs have the same name

Comment: @albert How would this affect the textarea control.  Multiple controls can have the same name such as radio button groups.

Comment: well if that ain't it, look at the tr var. looks like you are searching for the next table row, but the textarea is in the next table data cell.

Comment: @albert I did a little more digging on why MVC was rendering two input controls for the checkbox and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860940/why-does-the-checkboxfor-render-an-additional-input-tag-and-how-can-i-get-the-v

Comment: @albert The tr variable gets the row containing the checkbox and adds the class to it.  The textarea control affected is in the same row.  Nowhere is it searching for the next row.

Comment: @Ray The only elements that should ever have the same name are radio buttons and checkboxes because they are presented in groups. For radio buttons, it's mandatory to get mutual exclusivity. For check boxes, it's not. In your case, you have a hidden input field with a duplicate name, but no id. This can become a problem when trying to access an element directly by its id, as the wrong element could be chosen. This may not be the problem here, but it is bad coding convention in general.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding your question/problem because with your code, I can edit the textarea regardless of whether the checkbox is checked.

Comment: @ScottMarcus MVC adds the second hidden input control when using the CheckBoxFor HTML helper; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860940/why-does-the-checkboxfor-render-an-additional-input-tag-and-how-can-i-get-the-v.

Comment: @Ray Your post makes no mention of a second hidden input control, MVC or shows any of its code!  Please rework your question to be accurate about what you are doing and what you want to happen.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I was replying to your comment regarding two inputs having the same name.  The facts and code displayed are accurate in terms of the question.  Adding a class to the table row is somehow preventing editing in the textarea input element.  MVC is not an issue as the page has already been rendered and it is the javascript and jquery code that appears to be the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105964/discussion-between-ray-and-scott-marcus).

Comment: @Ray The extra code you mention is important for us to see because you are talking about components that affect the output and now you are talking about some mysterious second textarea. Since your question is about a textarea, I think it's important that we know about both of them.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You raised the issue of the checkbox and hidden inputs having the same name.  I responded with a link to a StackOverflow discussion detailing why MVC creates the hidden input field for the checkbox.  There is only one textarea - as I stated earlier MVC is inconsequential as the problem occurs in javascript after the page has been rendered.  At no point did I mention a "mysterious second textarea" so I don't know where you got this from.